# Titles ending with punctuation in biblatex-ieee

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I've just recently started using the `biblatex` package (with the `biblatex-ieee` style), and I've run into a small problem.  I've looked at the `.bbx` file, and it seems like it should be easy to change, although I'm perhaps not familiar enough with this to see how.

I have a citation with a title ending in a question mark, such as:

```
@article{Doe2012,
author={Doe, J.},
title={This title is a question?},
journal={Proc. IEEE},
year={2012},
volume={1234},
number={12},
pages={345--678},
month={Dec.},
}
```

This produces the something looking like:

> [1] J. Doe, “This title is a question?,” *Proc. IEEE*, vol. 1234, no.
>   12, pp. 345–678, Dec. 2012.

I would like to remove the comma following the question mark. The `bibtex` version of the IEEE style does not do this, and I don't remember seeing this kind of double-punctuation in any IEEE publications.  Naturally, I would like to keep the comma if the title does not end in a punctuation mark.  Otherwise, I think I could just use `\nopunct`.

Can anyone see how I might modify the style file to change this behaviour?

Comment: Probably a bug in `biblatex-ieee`: I will take a look.

Comment: Fixed in upcoming release: you can just use `\uspunctuation` in your preamble as a fix without needing `babel`.

Comment: Okay, that's good to have as well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the `babel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2012,
author={Doe, J.},
title={This title is a question?},
journal={Proc. IEEE},
year={2012},
volume={1234},
number={12},
pages={345--678},
month={Dec.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{Doe2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`biblatex` is aware of `babel` and uses it when deciding on how to deal with punctuation inside quotation marks.

[image: output of code]