# Comma in the title in the latest biblatex ieee-alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I have biblatex 2013/11/25 v2.8a and ieee-alphabetic.bbx 2013/10/25 v1.1j. Here [A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85418/titles-ending-with-punctuation-in-biblatex-ieee), it is said that the bug is fixed, but I happen to have it :(

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{filecontents}{mwwe.bib}
    @article{Test1,
    author = {An Author},
    title = {Nice title},
    journaltitle = {The Journal of Nonsense},
    date = {2012},
volume = {1},
number = {13},
pages = {13-23},
}

@book{Test2,
author = {Big Bethor},
title = {Some random Book},
    date = {1999},
    publisher = {Oneandonly Publishing},
    location = {Earth},
    pages = {18-22},
    }

    @inbook{Test3,
    author = {Crazy Cethor and Dumb Dethor},
    title = {Any weird title},
    booktitle = {The book of stuff},
    date = {1857},
    editor = {Edwin Editor},
    publisher = {Crazy Publishers},
    location = {The Universe},
    pages = {899-947},
    }
    @inproceedings{Test4,
    author = {Frank Fauthor and Gary Gethor},
    editor = {Oscar Odithor},
    title = {My Research},
    booktitle = {The Conference of Research},
    date = {2030},
    venue = {Vaduz, Liechtenstein},
    pages = {255-256},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, citestyle=alphabetic,
             bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic,  maxnames=3,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Test2}  \cite{Test1,Test4}   \cite{Test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Actually, I would like a semi-colon outside the quotation marks.

My log file, I use a localtexmf folder

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2013.9.14)  27 APR 2014 21:11
entering extended mode
**commaieee.tex
(D:\ptex\tout\commaieee.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

LaTeX Warning: File `mwwe.bib' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex2.sty
Package: biblatex2 2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/
AB)

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(D:\tex\miktex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(D:\tex\miktex\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(D:\tex\miktex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count90

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (D:\tex\miktex\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count91
\c@listtotal=\count92
\c@listcount=\count93
\c@liststart=\count94
\c@liststop=\count95
\c@citecount=\count96
\c@citetotal=\count97
\c@multicitecount=\count98
\c@multicitetotal=\count99
\c@instcount=\count100
\c@maxnames=\count101
\c@minnames=\count102
\c@maxitems=\count103
\c@minitems=\count104
\c@citecounter=\count105
\c@savedcitecounter=\count106
\c@uniquelist=\count107
\c@uniquename=\count108
\c@refsection=\count109
\c@refsegment=\count110
\c@maxextratitle=\count111
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count112
\c@maxextrayear=\count113
\c@maxextraalpha=\count114
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count115
\c@highnamepenalty=\count116
\c@lownamepenalty=\count117
\c@maxparens=\count118
\c@parenlevel=\count119
\blx@tempcnta=\count120
\blx@tempcntb=\count121
\blx@tempcntc=\count122
\blx@maxsection=\count123
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count124
\blx@notetype=\count125
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count126
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count127
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count128
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\shorthandwidth=\skip45
\biblabelsep=\skip46
\bibitemsep=\skip47
\bibnamesep=\skip48
\bibinitsep=\skip49
\bibparsep=\skip50
\bibhang=\skip51
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count129
\c@maxcomprange=\count130
\c@mincompwidth=\count131
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex citestyle data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'alphabetic.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex bibstyle data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee-alphabetic.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count132
\c@savedafterword=\count133
\c@annotator=\count134
\c@savedannotator=\count135
\c@author=\count136
\c@savedauthor=\count137
\c@bookauthor=\count138
\c@savedbookauthor=\count139
\c@commentator=\count140
\c@savedcommentator=\count141
\c@editor=\count142
\c@savededitor=\count143
\c@editora=\count144
\c@savededitora=\count145
\c@editorb=\count146
\c@savededitorb=\count147
\c@editorc=\count148
\c@savededitorc=\count149
\c@foreword=\count150
\c@savedforeword=\count151
\c@holder=\count152
\c@savedholder=\count153
\c@introduction=\count154
\c@savedintroduction=\count155
\c@namea=\count156
\c@savednamea=\count157
\c@nameb=\count158
\c@savednameb=\count159
\c@namec=\count160
\c@savednamec=\count161
\c@shortauthor=\count162
\c@savedshortauthor=\count163
\c@shorteditor=\count164
\c@savedshorteditor=\count165
\c@translator=\count166
\c@savedtranslator=\count167
\c@labelname=\count168
\c@savedlabelname=\count169
\c@institution=\count170
\c@savedinstitution=\count171
\c@lista=\count172
\c@savedlista=\count173
\c@listb=\count174
\c@savedlistb=\count175
\c@listc=\count176
\c@savedlistc=\count177
\c@listd=\count178
\c@savedlistd=\count179
\c@liste=\count180
\c@savedliste=\count181
\c@listf=\count182
\c@savedlistf=\count183
\c@location=\count184
\c@savedlocation=\count185
\c@organization=\count186
\c@savedorganization=\count187
\c@origlocation=\count188
\c@savedoriglocation=\count189
\c@origpublisher=\count190
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count191
\c@publisher=\count192
\c@savedpublisher=\count193
\c@language=\count194
\c@savedlanguage=\count195
\c@pageref=\count196
\c@savedpageref=\count197
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 
\c@textcitecount=\count198
\c@textcitetotal=\count199
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count200
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count201
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count202
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count203
\c@smartand=\count204
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'ieee-alphabetic'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee-alphabetic.bbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex-ieee\ieee-alphabetic.bbx
File: ieee-alphabetic.bbx 2013/10/25 v1.1j biblatex bibliography style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'ieee'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.bbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex-ieee\ieee.bbx
File: ieee.bbx 2013/10/25 v1.1j biblatex bibliography style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.bbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\bbx\numeric-comp.bbx
File: numeric-comp.bbx 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\bbx\numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\bbx\standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count205
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count206
)))))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'alphabetic'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'alphabetic.cbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\cbx\alphabetic.cbx
File: alphabetic.cbx 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(D:\tex\latex\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count207
\@quotereset=\count208

(D:\ptex\tout\commaieee.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'commaieee.bbl' found.
 (D:\ptex\tout\commaieee.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 50.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 50.
Requested font "cmr12" at 14.4pt
Requested font "cmbx12" at 14.4pt
Requested font "cmti10" at 10.0pt
 [1

]
(D:\ptex\tout\commaieee.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'commaieee.run.xml'.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5839 strings out of 429025
 98608 string characters out of 3170138
 478622 words of memory out of 3000000
 9095 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4591 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 912 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,49p,823b,868s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on commaieee.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: You are not seeing the bug you refer to, but simply the effect of the `\uspunctuation` option that apparently this style uses by default. If you don't want it, just put `\stdpunctuation` after loading `biblatex`. (The illogical but tidy placement of the punctuation that you observe is correct in the US.) Your other request (the semicolon instead of the comma, which seems very odd to me indeed), is rather harder because the punctuation that is placed at this point is defined by `\newunitpunct` and if you change that you get semicolons all over the place. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I have been playing with \DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{%
\uspunctuation} changing british with american and \uspunctuatiion with \stdpunctuation. The result is the same as the first post.

Comment: Also, I do not want the semi-colon everywhere. A comma would be enough just after the title in quotation marks. A semi-colon would separate more the title from the journal and the rest. The real problem is to remove the comma in the quotation marks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, the IEEE style follows US conventions for punctuation next to quotations: the punctuation is moved 'inside' the quote. This can be prevented by loading an appropriate `babel` definition, for example

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Test1,
    author = {An Author},
    title = {Nice title},
    journaltitle = {The Journal of Nonsense},
    date = {2012},
volume = {1},
number = {13},
pages = {13-23},
}

@book{Test2,
author = {Big Bethor},
title = {Some random Book},
    date = {1999},
    publisher = {Oneandonly Publishing},
    location = {Earth},
    pages = {18-22},
    }

    @inbook{Test3,
    author = {Crazy Cethor and Dumb Dethor},
    title = {Any weird title},
    booktitle = {The book of stuff},
    date = {1857},
    editor = {Edwin Editor},
    publisher = {Crazy Publishers},
    location = {The Universe},
    pages = {899-947},
    }
    @inproceedings{Test4,
    author = {Frank Fauthor and Gary Gethor},
    editor = {Oscar Odithor},
    title = {My Research},
    booktitle = {The Conference of Research},
    date = {2030},
    venue = {Vaduz, Liechtenstein},
    pages = {255-256},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, citestyle=alphabetic,
             bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic,  maxnames=3,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage[]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{Test2}  \cite{Test1,Test4}   \cite{Test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

or by setting 'standard' punctuation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Test1,
    author = {An Author},
    title = {Nice title},
    journaltitle = {The Journal of Nonsense},
    date = {2012},
volume = {1},
number = {13},
pages = {13-23},
}

@book{Test2,
author = {Big Bethor},
title = {Some random Book},
    date = {1999},
    publisher = {Oneandonly Publishing},
    location = {Earth},
    pages = {18-22},
    }

    @inbook{Test3,
    author = {Crazy Cethor and Dumb Dethor},
    title = {Any weird title},
    booktitle = {The book of stuff},
    date = {1857},
    editor = {Edwin Editor},
    publisher = {Crazy Publishers},
    location = {The Universe},
    pages = {899-947},
    }
    @inproceedings{Test4,
    author = {Frank Fauthor and Gary Gethor},
    editor = {Oscar Odithor},
    title = {My Research},
    booktitle = {The Conference of Research},
    date = {2030},
    venue = {Vaduz, Liechtenstein},
    pages = {255-256},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, citestyle=alphabetic,
             bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic,  maxnames=3,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\stdpunctuation

\begin{document}
\cite{Test2}  \cite{Test1,Test4}   \cite{Test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The issue you link to in the question ([Titles ending with punctuation in biblatex-ieee](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85418/titles-ending-with-punctuation-in-biblatex-ieee)) is about article titles ending in a punctuation character, where the IEEE style is to omit the comma which would normally be added as part of the style. Note that with 'standard' punctuation, the comma will 'reappear' as the suppression no longer makes sense.

Comment: Note: from a 'bug' point of view this is STATUS:BYDESIGN